# Are the verb suffixes -eth and -est always present tense?

Tags: suffixes, present-tense

Are the verb suffixes -eth and -est always present tense?

Wondering if these suffixes imply present action.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.** (Mostly.)

Early Modern English had the following *present tense* verb conjugation:

```
I go.
Thou goest.
He goeth.
We/you/they go.
```

So much like Modern English *-(e)s*, these endings are only used in the present tense (with one exception shown below).

The *simple past* conjugation was as follows:

```
I did.
Thou didst.
He did.
We/you/they did.
```

As you can see above, the ending *-eth* does not occur in the past tense, but the ending  *-st* (when preceded by the normal simple past ending *-ed*) does.

Comment: Or not preceded by _-ed_ for strong verbs, eg _thou gavest_, _thou wrotest_.